# EF Core sum on nested collection's properties does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My database has the following structure: One User can have many Accounts. One Account can have many Transfers.

This is the map configuration. I want to store in my DTO information about each user and his total savings in every account. (the code below represents one part of the whole configuration).

```
this.CreateMap<User, UserTestModel>()
    .ForMember(
        utm => utm.AccountsSavings, 
        options => options.MapFrom(u => u.Accounts
            .Select(a => a.Transfers.Sum(t => t.Amount))
            .ToList()));
```

My query to the database (I am using EF Core 3.1.3 with Sqlite database) looks like this:

```
var resultSet = await this._dbContext.Users
    .ProjectTo<UserTestModel>(this.Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However the following exception is thrown.

*

> > System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> >             .Where(t => EF.Property>((EntityShaperExpression: 
> >                 EntityType: Account
> >                 ValueBufferExpression: 
> >                     (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> >                 IsNullable: False
> >             ), "Id") != null && EF.Property>((EntityShaperExpression: 
> >                 EntityType: Account
> >                 ValueBufferExpression: 
> >                     (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> >                 IsNullable: False
> >             ), "Id") == EF.Property>(t, "AccountId"))
> >             .Sum(t => t.Amount)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client
> >     evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
> >     AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

*

Is this a problem with my code, or rather with some of the frameworks I am using at the moment (AutoMapper or EF Core)?

**Edit 1:**

I decided to try to manually gather that information from the `User` entities but that code leads to the same exception which means that it is not Automapper's fault:

```
var resultSet = await this._dbContext.Users
    .Select(u => u.Accounts.Select(a => a.Transfers.Sum(t => t.Amount)).ToList())
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Edit 2:**

Created issue at EntityFrameworkCore's GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20455

Comment: Try writing it in LINQ, without AM, does that work? If it does, check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html) and find the difference.

Comment: It looks like EF Core also cannot cope with that expression. So this is not a problem with AutoMapper.

Comment: That makes sense. Open a issue in their repo, maybe you'll get a workaround :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I thought about it but the last time I had to wait over 2 months to get a response and decided this time to try with StackOverflow. Eventually there I may have a concrete answer faster.. :D

Comment: @TonyTroeff Can't reproduce. Consider adding full repro (they will request the same for your GitHub issue).

Comment: @IvanStoev You mean that it worked with your implementation?

Comment: Correct, it works with a sample model I've tried based on information you've posted. EF Core 3.1.3, SqlServer if that matters.

Comment: @IvanStoev, could you please try it with Sqlite?

Comment: @TonyTroeff That was it! See below. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce it with SQLite provider and `Amount` type being `decimal` (works fine with SqlServer provider).

So you seem to be hitting the following SQLite [Query Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations#query-limitations) from EF Core documentation:

> SQLite doesn't natively support the following data types. EF Core can read and write values of these types, and querying for equality (where e.Property == value) is also supported. Other operations, however, like comparison and ordering will require **evaluation on the client**.
>
> - DateTimeOffset
> - **Decimal**
> - TimeSpan
> - UInt64

As workaround, consider taking the advice from the docs:

> The `Decimal` type provides a high level of precision. If you don't need that level of precision, however, we recommend using double instead. You can use a value converter to continue using decimal in your classes.

with sample

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.DecimalProperty)
    .HasConversion<double>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me solve the issue.